# Yellowing of peach tree leaves

Tags: peaches

I've read Levi's questions, and your responses; however, watering is not an issue w/my trees as we've had consistent/adequate rain all summer long, and the landscape is lush and green; a neighbor has a peach of similar size that looks very healthy.  Unlike Levi, my 2 trees were grown from pits and now are about 2 yrs old, and about 3' tall.  All the leaves, on both trees, are a consistent yellow, and have been for the entire growing season.  The trees are planted at the edge of my garden, approx 5' from our lawn, which is treated by a lawn service, which makes me wonder if they are getting inadequate/inappropriate chemicals?  Could the yellowing be caused by an iron deficiency?

Comment: Check the leaves to see if they have green veins that you can see in them. This is the biggest indication of an iron deficiency in yellowing leaves.

Comment: pictures please

Comment: This probably is a lack of minerals or fertilizer. Adding good ripe compost should help. Difficult to be sure without the pictures, though.

Comment: Who is Levi? You need to provide a link.